# Azure MySQL: SSL Connection Error: Unable to get certificate

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, azure-mysql-database

I have been trying to connect to Azure MySQL database via MySQL Workbench *v8* by following [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-configure-ssl).

Although I am able to connect to the MySQL server via **command line**, the same connection via MySQL Workbench does not succeed. It throws an error: **SSL Connection Error: Unable to get certificate**.

Can somebody tell what am I doing wrong with MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution.
Download BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem from [this link](https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem)
and include this certificate in SSL-CA file path and set useSSL field to "Require" in MySql workbench. Keep other fields empty.

Check this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYeYg.png) for the configuration.